# Could not open a file under a specific directory with a specific file name length in python

Tags: python, linux, google-compute-engine

I was writing lots of small text files in a specific directory (`/mnt/disks/hdd/chunk`) in my Linux system using a python script. my disk is 3TB and formated as ext4

I check the disk space and the available inode is enough. When I remove some of the character from the file name of `UCHLqIOMPk20w-6cFgkA90jw_id_V_YudpRpUpY_180.txt`. It can open under `/mnt/disks/hdd/chunk` without any issue. For example, If I change the file name to

```
UCHLqIOMPk20w-6cFgkA90jw_id_V_YudpRpUp_180.txt
```

It  opens without any issue. Here is some code snippets go get more clear idea

```
Cell In[5], line 1
----> 1 with open('/mnt/disks/hdd/chunk/UCHLqIOMPk20w-6cFgkA90jw_id_V_YudpRpUpY_180.txt', "w") as fp:
      2     print(fp)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:282, in _modified_open(file, *args, **kwargs)
    275 if file in {0, 1, 2}:
    276     raise ValueError(
    277         f"IPython won't let you open fd={file} by default "
    278         "as it is likely to crash IPython. If you know what you are doing, "
    279         "you can use builtins' open."
    280     )
--> 282 return io_open(file, *args, **kwargs)

OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/mnt/disks/hdd/chunk/UCHLqIOMPk20w-6cFgkA90jw_id_V_YudpRpUpY_180.txt'

In [6]: with open('/mnt/disks/hdd/chunk/UCHLqIOMPk20w-6cFgkA90jw_id_V_YudpRpUp_180.txt', "w") as fp:
   ...:     print(fp)
   ...: 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/mnt/disks/hdd/chunk/UCHLqIOMPk20w-6cFgkA90jw_id_V_YudpRpUp_180.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

Is this the file name length issue? I also try to open file in different directory (`/mnt/disks/hdd/`) rather than `/mnt/disks/hdd/chunk` and give long length file name like bellow

```
In [9]: with open('/mnt/disks/hdd/UCHLqIOMPk20w-6cFgkA90jw22222222222222222222222222_id_V_YudpRpUpY_180.txt', "w") as fp:
   ...:     print(fp)
   ...: 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/mnt/disks/hdd/UCHLqIOMPk20w-6cFgkA90jw22222222222222222222222222_id_V_YudpRpUpY_180.txt' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

And it does not cause any **No space left on device**. Could not get what i'm doing wrong?

So far I try,

- I try to clear /tmp directory and remount the HDD
- check free inode

Please let me know if you need any other information

Thanks

Comment: What file system are you using?

Comment: Could you try different file lengths and try to open the file under the same folder? That will help determine the limit at which it fails. Your file name has a length lesser than the maximum 255 characters.

Comment: See https://www.google.com/amp/s/helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/top-3-ways-to-fix-no-space-left-on-device-error-in-linux/amp/

Comment: @Tarik I'm using ext4 file system

Comment: @Tarik I have already mentioned if it discards some chars from "UCHLqIOMPk20w-6cFgkA90jw_id_V_YudpRpUpY_180.txt" it causes no issue. And this file length does not exit 255 characters

Comment: @Tarik  I have already tried the link you provided. But it does not work for me :(

Comment: Sorry to be of so little help. This is quite puzzling. The next thing I would try is opening the file using C programming language.